# save and show blob data using grails and oracle

Tags: image, grails, blob

I want to save and show an image into blob field in oracle 10g using grails. If i use Long raw field in database then it works. But in case of blob field
it saves but doesn't show in the view page.

Here is the code:

```
        //Domain
    class Hotel{

      byte [] pic_

      static mapping={}


      static constraints = {}


    }

    //Controller

    Class contrl
    {

      def save() {
        def hotelInstance = new Hotel(params)
        if (!hotelInstance.save(flush: true)) {
        render(view: "create", model: [hotelInstance: hotelInstance])
        return
        }

          flash.message = message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code:       'hotel.label', default: 'Hotel'), hotelInstance.id])
          redirect(action: "show", id: hotelInstance.id)
        }

      }


    def displayLogo () {
      def sponsor = Hotel.get(params.id)
      response.contentType = "image/jpg"
      response.contentLength = sponsor?.pic_.length
      response.outputStream.write(sponsor?.pic_)
      response.outputStream.flush()
    }

      //View
      <td><img src="${createLink(action:'displayLogo ', id:hotelInstance?.id)}"     height="42"    width="42" /> </td>
```

Comment: This program works fine in MySql database(LongBlob field) without any changes. But not working in oracle

Answer (score 1):

Use a blob. Also your mime type is wrong

```
Hotel hotel = Hotel.get(params.id)
response.contentType = 'image/jpeg'
response.outputStream << hotel.pic_
response.outputStream.flush()
```

I also see there is a space after your action name in the `createLink`. I doubt that it is breaking anything, but get rid of it.

Comment: still problem.                                                      why this code works in case of LongRaw?